# How do I install/run kodi on raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, kodi, openelec, lxterminal

I have tried to install kodi by typing `sudo apt-get install open-elec` but it says there is no such thing.
Please help!
How do I install it by terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you should have just asked for what you wanted:

```
apt-get install kodi
```

For future reference, `apt` has a search feature:

```
apt-cache search kodi
```

This will return a list of packages with "kodi" in their name or short description.

Comment: Wow this soooo useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can also just deploy the preconfigured openElec Card

http://openelec.tv/get-openelec

Answer (score -1):

Use OSMC it's based on Kodi and it's pretty https://osmc.tv/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thx that was slightly useful