# My Kodi was working fine then it stopped working.

Tags: raspbmc

Kodi was working fine then it stopped working.  I tried to reinstall Kodi on a new SD card but NOOBS ver 1.9 does not have OpenELEC in it.  How do I get Kodi back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install/run kodi on raspbian?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39934/how-do-i-install-run-kodi-on-raspbian)

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [website](https://kodi.tv/download/) download the image file and image it your SD card using Win32DiskImager.

Answer (score 0):

LibreELEC has replaced OpenELEC on newer versions of NOOBS ([Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=150359))

From the NOOBS menu you should be able to successfully get KODI working with LibreELEC. There's a guide describing the procedure [here.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/kodi/README.md)